# Add library to linker

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker, ping, icmp

I'm trying to write code that sends a ping to another computer.
I need to include `icmpapi.h` to my program and add `icmp.lib` to the linking library list.I already included `icmpapi.h`, but when I build the program, I get allot of errors and- no function with C linkage found -  in the end
I am kind of new in visual studio ant it will be great if someone could help me with this one.

Thanks!

Comment: i have alot of missing ";"  ")"

Comment: but the important one is warning C4162: '__readfsbyte' : no function with C linkage found

Comment: warning C4162: '__writefsdword' : no function with C linkage found

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation for [IcmpSendEcho](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa366050%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), it's `Iphlpapi.lib` you want. You should also include `iphlpapi.h`.

Comment: in addition to icmpapi.h? how do i add it to the linker? or should i just include it?  thank you!

Comment: this is the log: file://c:\Users\dudire\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\ping\dudiping\Debug\BuildLog.htm